# using slug instead of ID in admin edit post url

Tags: posts, admin, wp-admin

In Admin, is there any way to use a slug instead of a post ID# within the URL that takes you to a post's edit screen.

So instead of:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=5562&action=edit
```

You would use something like:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?slug=home&action=edit
```

Or, since the database stores the slug in the column `post-name`:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post-name=home&action=edit
```

Of course, neither of these actually works. Is there some existing method for doing this using Wordpress' built-in URL parameters?

If not, what sort of function could be used in my theme's `functions.php` file that would make this work?

Comment: slugs aren't necessarily unique, so this would be prone to failure. why do you want to do this? what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's interesting, because I thought slugs were unique. I've often encountered a situation where I unknowingly created a post with the same title, and the slug generated appended with a number like '-2'. Anyway, I have a quick link to edit my home page created using Admin Menu Editor, but I had to duplicate and revise it, making the duplicate into the home page.  I deleted the old one and changed the slug for the new one to 'home' (like the old one had). Of course, now my quick link no longer works.  I'd like a link that always goes to edit page for my 'home' page, no matter what the ID is.

Comment: slugs only have to be unique within a post type on the same level of hierarchy. if you want something like you describe, direct your request to [`admin-post.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_%28action%29), do your lookup, and redirect to the normal admin url for that post.

Comment: How would you handle post revisions? Also why would you want this? Users shouldn't notice the URLs in the admin panel, are you trying to manually construct edit urls?

Comment: This may be a fringe case, Tom...

Comment: This may be a fringe case, Tom... we're using a theme that has a 'one page site'.  So I want a quick link to edit that home page. I add the link using Admin Menu Editor. Also, this is set up as a network of sites. Each of the other sites in network also has a 'one page' home page.  The 'EDIT HOME PAGE" link I created in Admin Menu Editor appears on ALL the network sites, but Site B's home page (where slug also equals 'home') has a different post ID, so the link goes nowhere on site b. This is a convenience issue for me primarily. I want quick access to edit the home page on each site.

Comment: Thanks, Milo.  Looks promising. I'll experiment with that.

Comment: I could use this to improve my automated test suite. so I could load up pages and posts by slug making the tests more readable and less fragile.

Answer (score 0):

If the home page is set as "Home" in settings, use:

```
get_edit_post_link( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
```

Comment: witch place I need to place it
it's not working when I put it in function